# App crashes when trying to run parse.com push notification application

Tags: java, android, xml, parse-platform, push-notification

My parse push notification app seems to crash whenever I run it. I double checked to make sure that the permissions were correct and that my build.gradle  was also correct. I created a Java class (which I added to the src folder) for the Parse Application. Here is the code for the Parse Application, my Android Manifest, and the build.gradle file.

**BUILD.GRADLE FILE**

```
buildscript {
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.anish.parseexample"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
    compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.2.jar')
}
```

**PARSEAPP.JAVA**

```
 package com.example.anish.parseexample;

 import android.app.Application;

 import com.parse.Parse;
 import com.parse.PushService;

 public class ParseApp extends Application {
 @Override
 public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Parse.initialize(this, "APP_ID_KEY_WAS_HERE", "CLIENT_ID_KEY_WAS_HERE");
    PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MainActivity.class);
}
}
```

**ANDROIDMANIFEST.XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2de.permission.RECEIVE"/>

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.example.ani.parseexample.ParseApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.ani.parseexample.ParseApp.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".ParseApp">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

<service android:name="com.parse.PushService"/>
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="com.example.ani.parseexample.ParseApp"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

</manifest>
```

**LOGCAT**

```
Service com.android.providers.media.MtpService has leaked IntentReceiver android.mtp.MtpDatabase$1@3b5d3c26 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Service com.android.providers.media.MtpService has leaked IntentReceiver android.mtp.MtpDatabase$1@3b5d3c26 that was originally registered here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher.<init>(LoadedApk.java:1003)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getReceiverDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:767)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiverInternal(ContextImpl.java:1749)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1729)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.registerReceiver(ContextImpl.java:1723)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.registerReceiver(ContextWrapper.java:488)
        at android.mtp.MtpDatabase.setServer(MtpDatabase.java:619)
        at android.mtp.MtpServer.<init>(MtpServer.java:33)
        at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.manageServiceLocked(MtpService.java:259)
        at com.android.providers.media.MtpService.onStartCommand(MtpService.java:219)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3072)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:155)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5696)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1028)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
```

If there is some information missing in the logcat, please let me know. I am using a phone to run the app, and it gives many error messages about other running processes in the system. I have turned the Parse-1.9.2.jar folder into a library, if that helps at all. I have also tried the parse example at https://parse.com/apps/quickstart#parse_push/android/native/existing but that hasn't worked either. Can someone please help?

Sincerely,

Ani

Answer (score 0):

Firstly.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2de.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

should probably be:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
```

`c2dm` not `c2de`

Also, in some places you use `com.example.anish` and in others you use `com.example.ani`. You should make sure you are consistent with the package as defined in your manifest/gradle.

In your `permission`, `uses-permission` and broadcast receiver you should be consistent. In your case your setup should be more like:

```
<!-- lowercase these 2 -->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/
<!-- end lowercase -->
...
<permission android:protectionLevel="signature" android:name="com.example.anish.parseexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.anish.parseexample.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
...
<receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver" android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
        <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION"/>
        <category android:name="com.example.ani.parseexample"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I've never used parse.com however, the above is based on my understanding of the [google cloud messaging setup](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client).